# Passing JVM args through sbt

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to add a 3rd party jar to my java library path. If I invoke sbt with `-Djava.library.path=a-3rd-party-lib.jar`, then it works for the *first invocation* of `run-main MyClass` inside sbt, but thereafter the 3rd party code complains that the jar is not in the java library path. I have also tried adding `javaOptions += "-Djava.library.path=a-3rd-party-lib.jar"` to my build.sbt file, but this hasn't worked (even for the first run). Qualifying this command as `javaOptions in (Test,run) += "-Djava.library.path=a-3rd-party-lib.jar"` (as seen in the docs) hasn't worked either.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a strange bug?

FYI I'm using sbt 0.13.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`javaOptions` only takes effect if you fork `run` and sbt does not fork by default.  See the [Forking](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Forking) documentation for details, but forking is enabled for `run` and `runMain` with:

```
fork in run := true
```

Comment: Your answer solved me an issue I had connecting to SQL Server with integratedSecurity=true via the microsoft jdbc driver 6.0. Before using the fork option, when I ran the app the first time it was ok, second time I would get: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\costa\AppData\Local\Temp\sbt_fbfea069\sqljdbc_auth.dll (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process). After using the fork option, it works fine every time.