# Play Framework -Dconfig.resource is not Working

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework

I am using Play 2.3.9 for Scala and SBT 0.13.5. I ran my test using an alternative configuration i.e.

```
sbt -Dconfig.resource=test-application.conf test
```

Play cannot find this configuration even it was located at `/conf`.  I tried without the `.conf` extension and placed it in different directories. In the end I used the known to be working `application.conf` and failed. Nothing seems to satisfy it. However, Play managed to pick the configuration file when I used `-Dconfig.file=/path/to/test-application.conf`. What I am missing here with `-Dconfig.resource`? Does `-Dconfig.resource` even work? Thanks.

Comment: Check your build.sbt if folder with test-application.conf is in classpath.

Comment: Try `activator -Dconfig.resource=test-application.conf test`

Comment: @mst test-application.conf and application.conf are located in conf/. I understand conf/ is part of the classpath's path.

Comment: @SteveChaloner the result is the same. an error was thrown during Activator startup. It cannot locate `test-application.conf` nor `application.conf`.

Comment: OTH, set `fork`  to `true` and `-Dconfig.resource` as `javaOptions` inside `build.sbt` works. SBT will not pick it up if it is not forked. Strictly, `javaOptions` only work with `fork` is set to `true` as mentioned [here][1]

Still, strangely, `-Dconfig.resource` in my original question **does not work** with the command line even though `test-application.conf` is in one of the classpaths.

 [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060623/passing-jvm-args-through-sbt

Answer (score 1):

your config file have to be in the "directory project_directory/conf" which should be on your class path and then eg. "sbt run -Dconfig.file=ci.conf" should work perfectly

Comment: I am referring to `config.resource`

Comment: did you create play project from scratch or using activator. I can try to repoduce you problemm - or maybe you can share your project on github?

Comment: I created a new project with activator