# Set javaOptions in Test for Play/SBT

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework

I configured build.sbt for the unit test to use a different Play (2.3.9 for Scala and SBT 0.13.5) configuration via,

```
javaOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Dconfig.file=/home/kitty/acme/test/resources/test-application.conf")
```

Play did not pick up `test-application.conf` and used `application.conf` in `conf` instead. AFAIK, there is no `scalaOption` in this case. However, if I include `-Dconfig.file` in the command line, it works fine,

```
sbt test -Dconfig.file=/home/kitty/acme/test/resources/test-application.conf
```

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

`javaOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Dconfig.file=/home/kitty/acme/test/resources/test-application.conf")` didn't work because my `fork in Test` was `false`. Therefore, set `fork`  to `true` and it will work. `-Dconfig.resource` like `-Dconfig.file` works the same way too. SBT will not pick it up if it is not forked. Strictly, `javaOptions` only work with `fork` is `true` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060623/passing-jvm-args-through-sbt)

Answer (score 1):

you're almost there, you can force JVM options like this

`javaOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Dconfig.file=/home/kitty/acme/test/resources/test-application.conf")`

*config.file* also takes a relative path e.g conf/test-application.conf

Comment: No. It does not work. It causes "Seq[String] cannot be appended to Seq[sbt.TestOption]" error during SBT `reload`. Then I try `testOptions in Test ++= Seq(Tests.Argument("-Dconfig.file=/home/kitty/test/resources/test-application.conf"))`, SBT continues but `test-application.conf` is not read.

Comment: my bad, typo in the answer. It's javaOptions, i'll amend

Comment: Is it not what I say that didn't work in my question?

Comment: I've just re-read, sorry you're right. This is working for me on 2.3.x and 2.4.x however i'm using a relative path from the conf/ directory, could you try that?

Comment: still no good. does it has something to do with `fork in Test := false` and `parallelExecution in Test := false`?